# Recognize RabbitMQ master node in high-availability cluster

Tags: rabbitmq, high-availability

I would like to run RabbitMQ [Highly Available Queues](http://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html) in a cluster of two RabbitMQ instances on two separate servers. It's not clear to me from the documentation how can I detect which node is considered as master by RabbitMQ in order to determine which node should I publish messages to and consume from.

Is that something that RabbitMQ resolves internally (and so I can publish and consume from master even when connected to a slave node) or should the application know about master node for each queue and connect only to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RabbitMQ will take care of that. The idea of HA queues is that you publish and consume from either node, and RabbitMQ will try to keep a consistent state.

Comment: I noticed this sentence in the linked documentation: "Consumers are connected to the master regardless of which node they connect to, with slaves dropping messages that have been acknowledged at the master." So you're basically right, thanks.